# ¿Cómo enviar todo el contenido de una jquery datatable a un método de acción del controlador?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, datatables

Tengo una vista en la que muestro unos campos de filtro, y mediante una función de JS "ObtenerDatos()" lleno un DataTable de jquery con Ajax.

En dicha tabla permito que el usuario pueda modificar algunos valores, y una vez que ha terminado, mediante un botón quiero enviar toda la lista modificada a un método de acción del controlador para procesar los cambios y actualizar la bbdd's.

¿Cómo puedo enviar esos datos al controlador?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es agregar una acción al momento de que el formulario hace la acción "submit"
Algo como:

```
$("#formid").on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        var data = new FormData($("#formid").get(0));
        var table = $("#Table1").DataTable();
        var cont = 0;
        table.rows().every(function () {
            var data = this.data();
            data.append('list[' + cont + '].campo1', data.valor1);
            data.append('list[' + cont + '].campo2', data.valor2);
            data.append('list[' + cont + '].campo3', table.cell(cont, 2).nodes().to$().find('input').val());
            data.append('list[' + cont + '].campo4', table.cell(cont, 3).nodes().to$().find('input').val());
            data.append('list[' + cont + '].campo5', table.cell(cont, 4).nodes().to$().find('input').val());
            cont++;
        });
});
$.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("Accion", "Controlador")",
        method: form.attr("method"),
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result == "Ok") {
Alert('Correcto')
            } else {
Alert('Algo ah salido mal')
            }
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, error) {

        }
    });
```

En tu controlador recibes la lista creada y el objeto del formulario:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public JsonResult accion(objeto objetoformulario, List<listaObjetos> list)
    {

        try
        {
            //hacer uso del objeto del formulario o recorrer la lista que mandaste con un foreach
            return Json("Ok");//si todo sale bien esto regresa al ajax de la vista
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return Json("error");//si todo sale mal esto regresa al ajax de la vista
        }
    }
```